# Printing complications with ArrayLists, what is the correct way?

Tags: java, printing, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists and I want to print them out such that each position in the array prints out next to the other.

```
ArrayList1String1 ... ArrayList2String1

ArrayList1String2 ... ArrayList2String2

ArrayList1String3 ... ArrayList2String3
```

I don't know how to do this, but there is another complication, the second array list I want to print is actually an ArrayList of ArrayLists... So I want to do this:

```
ArrayList1String ... ArrayList2-List1-String1 ... ArrayList2-List1-String2 ... ArrayList2-List1-String3 ...

ArrayList1String ... ArrayList2-List2-String1 ... ArrayList2-List2-String2 ... ArrayList2-List2-String3 ...

ArrayList1String ... ArrayList2-List3-String1 ... ArrayList2-List3-String2 ... ArrayList2-List3-String3 ...
```

I have been using and have been taught this method:

```
for(String arrayListVariable : ArrayList)
    System.out.print(arrayListVariable);
```

However, this method only prints out the array variables in a more downward motion:

```
arrayListVariable1
arrayListVariable2
arrayListVariable3
arrayListVariable4
and so on...
```

I tried it myself and it came out wrong every time. My most recent attempt:

```
for(String word : words && String fList : fLists)
        {
            out.write(?????);
            out.write();
        }
```

How is this manner of printing accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ArrayOfArrayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
  ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
  array.add("first.string1");
  array.add("first.string2");
  array.add("first.string3");
  ArrayOfArrayList.add(array);
  array = new ArrayList<String>();
  array.add("second.string1");
  array.add("second.string2");
  array.add("second.string3");
  ArrayOfArrayList.add(array);

  // assume array all have same number of elements;
  for (int i = 0; i < ArrayOfArrayList.get(0).size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ArrayOfArrayList.size(); j++) {
       System.out.print(ArrayOfArrayList.get(j).get(i) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

out put looks like this:

first.string1 second.string1

first.string2 second.string2

first.string3 second.string3

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you :D